# mongoose.createconnection missing database error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What I am trying to do is getting list of databases on my localhost server I get the ip address which is in this case local host and port of database server and calling the service Below.

The error I am getting in console is missing database name as I have to connect only database server where am I missing some thing?

```
app.post('/loadDataBase', function(req,res){
    app.set('mongoose').connection.close();
    var mongoose = require('mongoose')
       , Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;
// create a connection to the DB
  var connectionStr="mongodb://"+req.body.host+":"+req.body.port;
    /* var connection = mongoose.createConnection(
     'mongodb://127.0.0.1');*/
    var connection = mongoose.createConnection(connectionStr) ;
    connection.on('open', function() {
        // connection established
        new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {

            // database list stored in result.databases
            var allDatabases = result.databases;

            res.send(allDatabases);
        });
    });
});'
```

`app.set('mongoose').connection.close();` Will this close my previous mongoose connection?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with a mongod running locally on port 27017. It successfully prints out a list of databases, along with their sizeOnDisk.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Admin = mongoose.mongo.Admin;

var connection = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017') ;
connection.on('open', function() {
  // connection established
  new Admin(connection.db).listDatabases(function(err, result) {

    // database list stored in result.databases
    var allDatabases = result.databases;

    console.log(allDatabases);
  });
});
```

Can you give me your exact error output? This maybe could help me diagnose what the problem is.

As for your question about closing a previous mongoose connection: you can close the connection with mongoose.disconnect(). However, instead of connecting and disconnecting repeatedly, it is better to connect once when your application starts up and then disconnect when your application shuts down.